# How to combine a line (space-separated) and a file (one-value per line) into one?

Tags: sed, awk

Given a line

```
    100  90  80  70  60  50  40  30  20  10   0
```

and a file

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

How can I combine these two into one file which reads

```
100 1
90  2
80  3
70  4
60  5
50  6
40  7
30  8
20  9
10  10
0  11
```

I guess `sed` and `awk` are my friends, but have no experience with them ...

Comment: Separated is spelled with an a, not an e. You can remember this by the sentence: There is "a rat" in separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat file2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
$
$ cat file1
100    90        80  70      60 50 40 30 20 10 0
$
$ $ gawk '!NF{next} NR==FNR{a[++nr1]=$0;next} {print $0,a[++nr2]}' file2 RS="[[:space:]]+" file1
100 1
90 2
80 3
70 4
60 5
50 6
40 7
30 8
20 9
10 10
0 11
```

Comment: In what way? See my edited post. Note that I have a space at the end of file1, if you use GNU awk you can get rid of that and set RS="[[:space:]]".

Comment: in my file1, there's five spaces in between the entries, not just one. sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: Then use gawk and set RS to "[[:space:]]+". I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: thanks! this is almost right. I noticed my file2 starts with spaces, so the results of your answer are off by one line.

Comment: Hang on - in your updated question file1 now starts with spaces, not file2. Which is it?

Comment: I just updated my script so it will work if there's leading spaces in file1 and/or leading blank lines in file2.

Answer (score 3):

Or using `tr` and `paste`:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file1 | paste - file2
100     1
90      2
80      3
70      4
60      5
50      6
40      7
30      8
20      9
10      10
0       11
```

Comment: +1, but xargs seems like overkill.  `tr \  \\n` seems clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
paste <(printf '%s\n' 100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 0) file.txt
```

In this shot, `paste`, *process-substitution* & `printf` are your friends =)

### OUTPUT

```
100     1
90      2
80      3
70      4
60      5
50      6
40      7
30      8
20      9
10      10
0       11
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk:

```
awk '{if(NR==1) split($0,N); else print N[FNR], $0}' file1 file2
```